# I'm getting a TypeError for a += b, but not b += a (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

why I'm getting `TypeError` for `a += b` but it works fine for `b += a` for below code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((2,3), dtype=int) 
b = np.random.random((2,3))
a += b
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Report the whole TypeError!

```
----> 3 a += b

TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc add output from dtype('float64') to 
   dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

`a` is integer dtype, right?  `b` is float.  Add a float and integer and the result is a float.  But `a+=...` is expected to put that float into `a`, the integer array.  `numpy` does not want to do that.

But this is fine:

```
In [3]: a = a + b
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[1.01407496, 1.96122364, 1.91447533],
       [1.68130058, 1.99773138, 1.50043386]])
```

The original integer array, `a` has now been replaced by a float array.  That's a Python level assignment, where as `a+=...` attempts to modify the original `a` array (in-place).  The distinction is important.

Comment: It still seems strange to me that there is such a difference in python, but thanks, removing `+=` did the job.

Answer (score 5):

The error message will give you a hint:

> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc add output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') with casting rule 'same_kind'

`a` is an array of `int32`s and `b` is an array of `float64`s. Adding an `int32` and a `float64` (nevermind which comes first), will produce a `float64`. This value cannot be stored in `a`, but can be stored in `b`.

If you define `a` to use `dtype=float`, `a+=b` would be perfectly legal:

```
a = np.ones((2,3), dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `a` is a numpy array with types `int` and your variable `b` is a numpy array with types `float`. When add `b` to `a` it will try to convert these floats to integers which looses information. However, when you do it the other way around you cast an integer to a float, which is perfectly fine.